# how to find the errors of a non market android app when running in a device

Tags: android, apk

i am trying to run a non market app in my device. I am just trying to learn from that .apk file. The tutorial of the app says that it works good and fine. The app has worked in one of my device, but not working in other device. How can i know the errors which causing the app to get crashed....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you dont need to install and run the SDK to find out the stack trace. There are many applications available in the market that will let you view the log cat on the device.

I would beware though, that if you are not a software engineer, or dont have specific knowledge of android/java then the contents of the log might not be of much use to you.

Comment: I have used this one: https://market.android.com/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&feature=search_result There may be other equally good or better ones available though.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an Android development environment set up? If you're using Eclipse, you can: connect your device via USB, select it in the *Devices* pane of the *DDMS* perspective, and watch the *LogCat* window for exceptions or other clues to the cause of the problem.

Comment: What can i do if i dont have any Android development environment?!

Comment: You could: install the Android SDK ( http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html ); restart; connect your device via USB; open a command prompt; enter the `\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\ ` directory (probably under Program Files if on Win32); type `adb logcat`.

Comment: Actually, most of the information on that "Installing the Android SDK" page probably wouldn't be necessary if you don't want to develop anything. Just installing one of the packages from here may be enough: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use remote stack trace plugin like http://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/